# TASM 8086 Assembler Sound file

Tags: assembly, audio, tasm

i'v been asked to make a project for school work, and I'm doing a virtual piano. i have done all the graphics and animations already but now I need to actually play the sounds. is there a way to play wav/mp3 sound files in the 8086 assembler using TASM? (any other sound files are ok aswell). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes............

Comment: Sure, if you want to write a driver for whatever virtual sound card your emulator emulates, often SB16.  For MP3, you'd of course have to write or port an MP3 decoder, instead of just loading uncompressed PCM from a `.wav` file.  (An actual 8086 would be too slow to decode in real-time, but some emulators aren't trying to be cycle-accurate.  Or you could decode into a buffer once, and play it repeatedly, like a mod tracker.)

Answer (score 4):

School piano project for DOS usualy plays only single-voice tones using the motherboard speaker. Do you really need to write a sound player?

I managed to play sound files in MS-DOS 28 years ago using TASM 16bit program, though it was rather  complicated. Sound samples (extracted from WAV file or decoded from MP3 file) were stored to the one of two reserved memory buffers. *Direct Memory Access* channel was used to feed SoundBlaster's input port at the preprogrammed bitrate. When DMA was almost finished with the buffer, it triggered an interrupt which signalized to the main program that the other memory buffer needs to be loaded with a next portion of sound samples and DMA input redirected to the other buffer, so the both buffers alternated seamlessly.

Or, if your project is 32bit *Portable Executable* application for Windows, you can just import WinAPI function [PlaySound](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd743680(v=vs.85)) and furnish it with the sound file name.