# How to make background music to an Asemmbly 8086 Tasm Game

Tags: assembly, x86-16, audio-player, tasm, background-music

I have searched the web trying to find a way to get background music to run in the back of my Assembly(TASM) game for my final project at school, but I can't find the right solution.

Comment: Possibly with [mpg123](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mpg123/) mp3 player.

Comment: See also the questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66401934/tasm-8086-assembler-sound-file/66403090#66403090 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41359112/playing-wav-files-on-dosboxs-sound-blaster-device/41366818#41366818

Comment: What's the platform? MS-DOS?